# I will fall down

Tags: tense, modal-verbs, future-tense

He wanted to play with me, and he kept pulling my shirt.

Which of the following sentences is correct?

> Don't grab my shirt. I'll **fall** down.

> Don't grab my shirt. I'll **fell** down.

For future actions, do I use the present tense after it?

Comment: No. It's not the present tense after modal verbs, such as 'will'. It's the bare infinitive (infinitive without 'to').

Comment: This question may help: https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/72701/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course this one is correct...

> Don't grab my shirt. I'll fall down.

'fell' indicates that you are already down..:) Which of course doesn't make sense because you are saying that you will fall only if your friend grabs your shirt.